# Acer Aspire 5742Z - Windows 10 driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, acer-aspire

I tried to install Windows 10 on my Acer Aspire 5742Z which run perferctly under Windows 8.1. Problem is that the resolution is stuck at 1024x768, it has an Intel HD Graphics 300 chip and an Intel Pentium P6200 CPU. Thing is that on a friends laptop that has the HD Graphics 3000, Windows normally installed the drivers for it, it has an i3 processor though.

So I tried Windows Update, it does find drivers for it but cant install them (error 0x0000005), then I downloaded them from Intel themselves, problem is that the CPU is not listed under the supported devices and I therefore get a 'does not meet minumum requirements' when trying to execute the exe.

I thought that it should run under win10 too as it ran without a problem under win8. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can't install the latest driver, you can install the Intel Driver Update Utility that will attempt to detect and download the best driver available.
Also, you can install the official driver from Acer support page for your laptop. This isn't the best thing to do, because these drivers are older versions that might have incompatibilities with some software and games.